# Can’t install YugabyteDB in kubernetes cluster

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I have tried setting up YugaByte in Kubernetes and it keeps erroring out during installation. Can someone help here?

I have a Digital Ocean Kubernetes cluster and I am trying to install YugaByteDB over there. I am using Helm
I tried deploying yugabyte into Minikube in my local and it worked.
But when I am trying to do similar at Kubernetes it goes unresponsive for a while and then error out

With this command:

```
helm install yb-demo yugabytedb/yugabyte --namespace yb-demo --wait
```

It gives me this error: `Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition`.

I am following this: https://docs.yugabyte.com/preview/deploy/kubernetes/single-zone/oss/helm-chart/

I can see the pods from the cluster but they are reporting sync issues. Running:

```
kubectl get svc -n yb-demo
```

[image]

```
kubectl get pods -n yb-demo
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you hit a node count limit on your cluster, causing one master to go into pending status. That is why your helm deployment didn't complete.

You can customize the cores/mem allocated to each master at https://github.com/yugabyte/charts/blob/8ae394ed699bf55286dbe732b074023b7a3b55a5/stable/yugabyte/values.yaml#L21 if you are unable to increase resources on your k8s cluster.

All 3 masters need to start up for initialization of the cluster, though one of them can fail later.